# What does “a good bargain is a pick-purse” mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> A good bargain is a pick-purse.

I'm an English learner. I came across this sentence, but even though I figured out all the individual words, I didn't get the meaning of the whole thing. So can someone please do that for me?

Answer (score 2):

I believe this proverb simply means that one should beware of offers that seem too good to be true—that the offer might in fact be a scam, a con, or simply much worse that it first appears. The person making the offer is in fact a thief (perhaps metaphorically) for trying to deceive you into buying something far less valuable.

In a weaker sense, it may also be applied to mean that what appears to be a good deal may not be a deal at all if what you're buying has no use to you.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to @pswg's answer, it could also mean that a bargain is very good (somewhat redundant given the use of *good* in the sentence as well).  A common English phrase is *"That bargain is a steal!"* or *"It's a steal at that price!"*  As a *pick-purse* is a theft, it's easy to see the correlation.  Without the surrounding context of the sentence, it's difficult to be more conclusive.

Answer (score 0):

I had never previously encountered the word "pick-purse" and had to look up its meaning to confirm my guess. I also didn't realise that the expression "A good bargain is a pick-purse" is/was a proverb (until I read the answer from @p.s.w.g).

"Pickpurse" is [defined](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pickpurse) as "One who steals purses, or money from purses." [I initially assumed that this must be an AmE term, but it appears to date back at least to the 16th century.]

This is similar to the British word "pickpocket", which is [defined](http://www.chambers.co.uk/search.php?query=pickpocket&title=21st) as "a thief who steals from people's pockets, usually in crowded areas."

In AmE, "purse" usually [refers](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/purse) to "a small bag used especially by a woman to carry everyday personal items", which in BrE would normally be [called](http://www.chambers.co.uk/search.php?query=purse&title=21st) "a (woman's) handbag". (In BrE, "purse" [refers](http://www.chambers.co.uk/search.php?query=purse&title=21st) to "a small container carried in the pocket or handbag, for keeping cash, etc. in".)

So *pickpurse* and *pickpocket* appear to be similar in referring to a thief who tries to steal from people's pockets and bags.

The proverb *A good bargain is a pick-purse* is [attributed](http://www.giga-usa.com/quotes/authors/george_herbert_a005.htm) to George Herbert, Welsh poet (1593 - 1633), and listed in *Dictionary of quotations from Ancient and Modern, English and Foreign Sources*, Rev. James Wood, 1893.  I have been unable to find any explanation of the proverb's meaning.